# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer inpyhton

Tags: python, python-3.6, sftp, paramiko

giving the more than 19 records in list and passing it in loop by given sftp connection details, but the error is throwing after running 19 records. Below is my code.

```
import paramiko
import sys, os
import time 

lsit1 = ["CBCGG1900089HM", "CBCGG1900090HM", "CBCGG1900091HM", "CBCGG1900092HM", "CBCGG1900093HM", "CBCGG1900094HM", "CBCGG1900095HM", "CBCGG1900096HM", "CBCGG1900097HM", "CBCGG1900098HM", "CBCGG1900099HM", "CBCGG1900100", "CBCGG1900101HM", "CBCGG1900102HM", "CBCGG1900103HM", "CBCGG1900104HM", "CBCGG1900105HM", "CBCGG1900106HM", "CBCGG1900108HM", "CBCGG1900109HM", "CBCGG1900112HM", "CBCGG1900116HM", "CBCGG1900120HM", "CBCGG1900124HM", "CBCGG1900128HM", "CBCGG1900130HM", "CBCGG1900131HM", "CBCGG1900132HM", "CBCGG1900136HM", "CBCGG1900142HM", "CBCGG1900149HM", "CBCGG1900151HM", "CBCGG1900153", "CBCGG1900161", "CBDGG1900001", "BCYG1800038", "BCYG1800041", "BCYG1800045", "BCYG1800047", "BCYG1800049"]
col_id = []

def sftpfun(i):
    try:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname='abc.com',timeout=6000,username='abc',password='xxbb')
        ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
        print("bc")
        ftp.get(f'/CT_Logs/Optima660_Beijing/{i}/image_analysis.csv', f'/home/hvr/sftp_python/Optima660_Beijing {i}/image_analysis.csv')
        ssh.close()
    except:
        col_id.append(f"Optima660_Beijing/{i}")
        with open(f"/home/hvr/sftp_python/logs/sftp_logs.txt", 'w') as f:
            f.write(i)


for i,j in zip(lsit1,range(len(lsit1))):
    sftpfun(i)
    if j%15==0:
        time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community  my connection is disconnected every 19seconds

Comment: For one, you're not closing the SSH connection if there's an error, so it's possible the remote host starts blocking you when you're keeping connections open. You're also using a bare `except:`, so it's hard to ever know what the actual error is.

Comment: Secondly, I certainly hope that hostname, username, and password are not real credentials, since you've just leaked them to the Internet.

Comment: Also: why do you grab a new SSH connection for each item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single SSH/SFTP connection:

```
import time

import paramiko

items = [
    "CBCGG1900089HM",
    "CBCGG1900090HM",
    "CBCGG1900091HM",
    "CBCGG1900092HM",
    "CBCGG1900093HM",
    # ...
    "BCYG1800049",
]

with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(
        hostname="amecoll01.logon.ds.ge.com",
        timeout=6000,
        username="WSO",
        password="#AMEuser",
    )
    ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        src = f"/CT_Logs/Optima660_Beijing/{item}/image_analysis.csv"
        dest = f"/home/hvr/sftp_python/Optima660_Beijing {item}/image_analysis.csv"
        try:
            ftp.get(src, dest)
            print("OK", dest)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed", item, ":", e)
        if i % 15 == 0:
            print("Sleeping...")
            time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Socket is closed
getting error

Comment: Are you able to do this with a regular SFTP client, or do you get similar errors? You might need to talk with whoever's managing the SSH server.

Comment: if i give 19 records in list then its working fine, when i am increasing the id's in list more than 19 then the error is getting